# Does adding non-referenced alloc'd object to collection cause leak?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management, memory-leaks

Does the following line leak this object `[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]` ?

`[myCollection setObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] forKey:@"myDictionary"];`

I assume it doesn't because the object is never assigned to a reference... but at the same time I question it because I did alloc the object...

Would the following work as an alternative?

`[myCollection setObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionary] forKey:@"myDictionary"];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first will leak, the second will not.

Assigning an object reference into a variable does not affect ownership of the object at all.  You invoked `alloc`, which means that you are the owner, regardless of whether you capture the results of that call at all.  If you don't, you've leaked.

The second option (`[NSMutableDictionary dictionary]`) will not leak, since `+dictionary` returns a non-owned (autoreleased) object.

So in a nutshell, your intuition is correct.  Congratulations! Many people who ask memory management questions here usually get it wrong. :)

Comment: Thanks! Just needed a little confirmation :)